# AVFoundation AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer freezes after hours

Tags: avfoundation

I am using AVFoundation to monitor video and audio signals using AJA U-Tap SDI interface. Everything works as expected, but random freezes of the preview after a long period.  I noticed this 2-3 times for the last weeks. It happened after hours of the continual preview. No memory leaks, console messages, warnings, the session was running, and all allocated objects seemed valid. Has anybody noticed something like this? Thanks.
[macMini, BigSur 11.2.3, the latest AJA firmware]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using `AVCaptureSession`. Try subscribing to the following notifications for clues:

```
.AVCaptureSessionRuntimeError
.AVCaptureSessionDidStopRunning
.AVCaptureDeviceWasDisconnected
.AVCaptureInputPortFormatDescriptionDidChange
```

Comment: Hi, yes, right. I have all of them except the .AVCaptureSessionRuntimeError. I will check. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, after week of tests: it happened 2 times (when it happened, there was no UI interaction): no message in logs, no notification (I am observing all you mentioned). I was testing in Debug mode this time, so I paused and checked validity of relevant objects: session was running, previewlayer valid, etc. I tested on fresh new macMini and also macMini m1 (roseta, the same build) with the latest macOS/Xcode. I have no idea what it could be... my last suspicion is my `dispatch_queue_create("sr_capture_queue_video", NULL);` Could it be suspended by system and then resumed?

Comment: I also found this (might be related): using standard web cam or Apple Face Time HD camera, preview video (using AVCapturePreviewLayer too) is dropping frames approximately every 5 secs.for 1-2 secs. and most interesting is, that if I launch iMovie and open camare capture window, preview in both apps is smooth. Does iMovie switch the system / AVFoundation to some special mode? I am really sick of this... :-)  Thanks.

Comment: I switched to `- (void)captureOutput: (AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputSampleBuffer: (CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection`, get rid of AVCapturePreviewLayer, and video preview is smooth, no dropped frames.

Comment: Problem #2 (dropping and freezing preview): This is happens only when superLayer, parent of my previewLayer, has transform applied: `self.documentLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(_magnification, _magnification, 1);` and only when running on the internal GPU. Once I connected external display (and lid of MacBook is closed) or I removed transform no frame drops or freezes. I'm thinking of two solutions: force to switch to discreete GPU or find other way how to scale documentLayer.